# Android Dev: AlertDialog with SurfaceView

Tags: java, android

I am developing an Android game and I have my SurfaceView rendering the game and I want to make it so when the player loses or wins an AlertDialog pops up and either restarts the level or whatever.

Basically I have two questions:

1. How do I use AlertDialogs with SurfaceViews? Do I have to put it into the layout.xml or does it get coded into the UI part or the game thread part?
2. Is there a way to "restart" an activity so it doesn't make a new one just starts the current one over with the same "intent" it was given originally?

Thank You!

Comment: Unsure about this ... but check out http://www.andengine.org/ ... useful for creating games

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I am trying to build my game from the ground up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `this.Start();` on any event to restart the thread in your activity that's the answer of your second question.

Or you can use

```
if(maze.isGameComplete()) {
   AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
   builder.setTitle(context.getText(R.string.finished_title));
   LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
   View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.finish, null);
   builder.setView(view);
   View closeButton =view.findViewById(R.id.closeGame);

   closeButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View clicked) {
         if(clicked.getId() == R.id.closeGame) {
            context.finish();
         }
      }
   });

   AlertDialog finishDialog = builder.create();
   finishDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: Please ask question properly So i can help you.

Comment: Where in my code does this go? In the UI code, thread, or gameview?

Answer (score 1):

You can restart the activity from SurfaceView class but it is a 'dirty' way, it may flicker, it may take too much memory in the process and crash the application

```
Intent intent = ((Activity) getContext()).getIntent(); 
getContext().startActivity(intent); //start the same activity again
((Activity) getContext()).finish(); //finish the previous instance
```

The proper way is to reinitialize the game by writing a method which will reset all required variables, clear old objects from arraylists etc.

It is possible to use alert dialog, however a standard android dialog would look too basic for a nice game, hence it may be better to create just another gaphics object for the dialog and draw it on screen, which can be even animated... using a transparent activity is another possibility which gives more desing freedom.